# How to write job file for cluster computer?

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, hpc

I am very new to high performance computers. In my laptop, I can run a program by type the command like this "./prog". But in HPC, I am required to write a job file before running any job. I was given a simple job file to get start with. But it really confuses me:

```
#!bin/bash
# BSUB -q
#BSUB -o outfile -R “mem>10”
myjob arg1 arg2
#BSUB -J myjob
```

Any one have any experience dealing with this type of HPC? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Looks to me as if your cluster has an installation of IBM's LSF (Load  Sharing Facility).  Since IBM publish oodles of documentation, point your browser at http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/technicalcomputing/platformcomputing/products/lsf/index.html  Or, consult whoever manages your cluster or supports its use.

Comment: also, learn more about [MPI](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HPC system is called LAVA queue system, developed by HP, if I remember it correctly.
I hope the following can answer your question:

---

- Lava frequently used commands at a glance**

`bhosts -w`
Show status of each node in one line

`bhosts -l`
Show details of status of each node

`bqueues [-l -w -r]`
Show status of each node by users’ group

`bparams [-l -h -V]`
Show available parameters for bjobs

`lsid`
display current lava version number

`lsinfo`
display load sharing information

`lshotst`
display hosts and their static resource information

`lsload`
display load information for hosts

`bjobs -u all`
display job info

`bjobs <job-id>`
display job info by its ID

`bjobs -a`
display all jobs

`bjobs -r/-p/-s`
show jobs that are running/paused/suspended

`bjobs -l`
 show more details

`bhist`
show job history

**Submit jobs**

```
bsub my_job
bsub < myscript
bsub -n 4  myjob
bkill 1234
bstop 1234
bresume 1234
```

More reference can be found at:

http://ccls.lab.sfsu.edu/bin/view/Cluster/LavaSchedulerInformation